# View websites that expect JavaScript, without executing JavaScript

Tags: open-source, javascript, web-browser, web, caching

Sadly, it has become increasingly common for websites - even ones that simply present some static page content - to be built on the assumption that the user will blindly execute untrusted, [proprietary JavaScript](https://www.fsf.org/campaigns/freejs) in their browser.

For users who do not wish to do this, are there any good [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Free_software&oldid=695656324#Definition_and_the_Four_Freedoms) web browser extensions (or indeed web browsers) that will pull those web pages' text content from a rendering/caching service that provides a static text view (e.g. [Google cache](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/askjack/2012/jun/21/internet-cache-email-google)) instead of from the website's webserver, if encountering such JavaScript?

I suppose that what I am seeking might be termed a "caching, rendering proxy" or a "caching, JavaScript-rendering proxy".

Comment: The caching services provide the exact same experience as surfing with JS turned off, hence you just need to disable JS. Besides, the concept of "proprietary JS" is a common FSF-caused misconception, as JS can be considered **content** you access through a browser, not software you have installed on your PC.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, *"The caching services provide the exact same experience as surfing with JS turned off, hence you just need to disable JS."* That is false. Turn off JavaScript in your browser, and compare [this "Text-only version" from Google's cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:7VUW6acbkzwJ:www.asauk.net/conferences/asauk-16/&num=1&hl=en&gl=uk&strip=1&vwsrc=0), which is very readable, with [the original](http://www.asauk.net/conferences/asauk-16/), which isn't.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, *"the concept of "proprietary JS" is a common FSF-caused misconception, as JS can be considered **content** you access through a browser, not software you have installed on your PC."* Well, you can consider it to be **content** or **form** or **a clown named Buttons** or whatever else you wish. Nevertheless, if a user has a typical modern Web browser & does not disable JavaScript, then any JavaScript embedded in or linked from a Web page viewed in that browser will be executed on the user's PC, regardless of whether it is obfuscated & regardless of its license terms.

Comment: Therefore, according to your bizzare definition, it is OK if you do not run "proprietary JS" but it is OK if somebody else (in this case Google) runs it through their proprietary web crawler on their proprietary servers so you can consume it? That's one of the weirdest form of GNU puritanism ever. Not to mention the fact that JS is minified for performance reason. CSS has been proved to be Turing complete, do you also check the license of the stylesheets of websites you visit?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, *"CSS has been proved to be Turing complete"*. I was not aware of this. It was not thought to be true the last time I checked, but that was before 2011, which is when the proof was published. I quite often use browsers that ignore sites' stylesheets. I'll probably do that more often now. *"one of the weirdest form of GNU puritanism ever."* It is obviously not GNU puritanism, for the reasons you have given. But it is pragmatic. Reducing the amount of untrusted JavaScript I execute reduces my PC's performance burden and attack surface. I hope you'd agree that's desirable.

Comment: if you are talking to me about security then yeah, you're preaching to the choir. **I 100% agree with that.** Browser history enumeration attacks have shown that even CSS is not very good sometimes. What I was arguing against is the definition of "proprietary JS". Aside that bit, if you are asking about pre-rendering webpages from a secure offsite location, I believe something like [Browserling](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/browserling-cross-browser/chfdigebbepdmeelcfiefkklfldmmgld) (or similar) might even be better. JS, but not on your machine.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, thanks. I'm not clear whether the client side of Browserling is free software. If it is (or if you know of something like it that is), and if it can divert the user to viewing its server-side output instead of the original in cases where the client would otherwise be exposed to JavaScript calls, please post that as an answer. Thanks!